# In React, in a nested component, can I render a sibling component which properties are calculated by the previous sibling component's rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to render a component child that depends on data that is constructed when rendering previous sibling component.

I want to use the fact that React follows a strict order when rendering nested components. The code explains itself:

```
const DQCustomLayout = ({ document, questionIDs, }) => {

  const layoutIDtoQuestionDict = useSelector((state) => state.dqN.LayoutIDtoQuestionDict);

  const questionsPendingToBeRendered = [...questionIDs];
  const handleQuestionRendered = (questionID) => {
    const i = questionsPendingToBeRendered.indexOf(questionID);
    if (i == -1) { return; }
    questionsPendingToBeRendered.splice(i, 1);
  };

  if (!document) {  // ...or error in parsing
    console.log("DQCustomLayout no document");
    return null;
  }
  else {
    return (
      <View>
        { document.children.map((node, i) => { 
          return (
            <Node 
              key={i} 
              node={node} 
              index={i} 
              layoutIDtoQuestionDict={layoutIDtoQuestionDict}
              onQuestionRendered={handleQuestionRendered}
            />
          );
        })}
        <DQNoLayout questionIDs={questionsPendingToBeRendered} />
      </View>
    );
  }

};

export default DQCustomLayout;
```

The View renders a tree-like structure that updates a list of the elements being rendered.
The list is not stored as state because it is being used in the same rendering.
DQNoLayout needs the View rendering to finish to have the full list of pending-to-render elements before start to render itself.

Note I'm assuming that React will first render all the Node tree BEFORE starting to render DQNoLayout component. Then the process of rendering the Node tree will modify the questionsPendingToBeRendered list and it will be safely available for DQNoLayout to use. It strongly relies in the order of execution that React employs when calling child components.

This apparently works. But I want to be sure it is a valid React usage.
Summarizing, my questions are:

Is this a valid React usage scenario, based on the rendering order React uses?

Is it correct to use the variable questionsPendingToBeRendered the way it is being used, not as a state but as a local variable being modified by "state-set-alike" function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is valid React code.

That said, I wonder why you wouldn't make `questionsPendingToBeRendered` a state variable?  Would you not want to re-render if `questionsPendingToBeRendered` got a new value (i.e. render after calling `handleQuestionRendered()`) ?

Comment: I just don't want the DQCustomLayout to be re-rendered, that is why. I have a list of "questionIDs" that are components to be rendered. Some of them are referenced in the "document" (an html working as a layout template). If some of the "questions" are not referenced in the layout then I need to render them at the end, as a column list. All that in a single DQCustomLayout rendering. Just one of my concerns was if I store questionsPendingToBeRendered as a state it will cause DQCustomLayout to be re-rendered... may be even each time a child node modifies the list?

Comment: Then there is no point to calling `.splice()`.  On every single render, the array gets created, populated with `[...questionIDs]`, if `handleQuestionRendered()` gets called the array is spliced.....but then on the next render the array is recreated with `[...questionIDs]`.

Comment: I added the code for the Node component for the better understanding of the logic. In one single rendering of the DQCustomLayout, multiple Node are rendering first. Each of them "consumes" a questionID from the original list that DQCustomLayout receives. Then, when all the Node tree is rendered, but the DQNoLayout have not started to render, the questionsPendingToBeRendered list can contain some IDs that were not rendered because they were not referenced in the Layout document. Then DQNoLayout should render that list. Let me stress: each Node rendering removes one element of that list.

Comment: It would be interesting to see this code running in a Snack so we could play with it.